# Python try except not executing the If inside it

Tags: python, loops, try-except

My program is expected to write prime numbers, happy numbers in separate files. Read them and print the overlapping numbers, My code is well written but am not getting the expected output. Am getting the output of functions primew(),happyr(),primer(),ishr() but am not getting the output of overlap()

```
def primew():
 a=0
 b=open("prime.txt","w")
 while a<1000: 
  if a in (2,3,5,7):
     b.write(str(a)+" ")
  elif a%2!=0 and a%3!=0 and a%5!=0 and a%7!=0 :
       b.write(str(a)+" ")
  a+=1
def primer():
 a=open("prime.txt")
 for b in a:
   print ("Prime numbers are: ")
   print(b)
def ish(n):
  rem=0
  s=0
  while n>0:
   rem=n%10
   s=s+(rem*rem)
   n=n//10
  return s
def ishr():
 b=open("happy.txt","w")
 for i in range(1,1000):
  result=i
  while result!=1 and result!=4:
   result=ish(result)
   if result==1:
    b.write(str(i)+" ")
    

def happyr():
 bb=open("happy.txt")
 for a in bb:
   print("Happy numbers are: ")
   print(a)
def overlap():
 b=open("happy.txt")
 c=open("prime.txt")
 for x in b:
  for y in c:
    try:
       if (int(x)==int(y)):
          print("Overlapping are: ")
          print(x)
    except: pass 
happyr()
primew()
primer()
ishr() 
overlap()
```

Comment: No so much related to your actual problem, but here's a free tip: fix your indentation first, and make it perfectly consistent. Python relies on it, and really bad things can happen if you don't stick to it. Use 4 spaces as the default indentation.

Comment: An opened file can be iterated only once because the file pointer is at the end then. Reset it with `seek` or store files as lists of lines and iterate over them.

Comment: Also the order that you call the functions right now will cause an error before it gets past the first one.

Comment: How do you know the code doesn't execute the `if`? Just because it doesn't execute the `print()` inside the `if`? These are two different things. Try adding an `else: print(x, y)` and see what happens. I bet it will highlight the issue.

Comment: `with open` is a safer way to manipulate files. When using `open` you need to close them manually each time you are done with them.

Comment: You need to close the files when you're done writing them. Otherwise the last buffer won't be written.

Comment: The over lap function would be a little more efficient if you only loop through b and just check if it's in c. You don't even need to parse them into an int that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the value is not being converted to an int properly on this line for `if (int(x)==int(y))`.

You can try printing the output of the except statement to see if it is catching an error:

```
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

It is most likely an int conversion error after reading from the file.